# Font rendering in Chrome is affected by focusing unrelated input element

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts

When an input element is focused, Chrome changes the font rendering of other unrelated elements.

Here is a MCVE:

```html
<body style="background-color: black;">
    <input value="Click here 1">
    <p style="color: red">This text changes when you click input, then click white text</p>
    <p style="color: white">This text doesn't change (click here 2)</p>
</body>
```

If you run the snippet, and you click between the input field and the white text element, you will see that the red text element font rendering changes.

I'm able to reproduce this issue in Chrome, but not in Firefox.

It does not make sense to me why the font rendering of the red element should change depending on which of these 2 other unrelated elements are being focused.

Also, it does not make sense to me why this issue affects only some color combinations (e.g. affects red on black, but does not affect white on black).

Also, it does not make sense to me why the "Computed" tab in Chrome dev tools is pretending to be rendering the text in the same manner in both cases, when clearly the text is being differently rendered in these cases.

I discovered [from another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72213663/wierd-font-rendering-in-chrome) that I'm able to "fix" the issue by setting `backface-visibility: hidden;` on the red element. When I set that, the font is now rendered the same way regardless of which element is being focused. However, it does not make sense to me why backface-visibility should have *any* effect in this case. Based on reading the spec, it sounds like this is a bug in Chrome.

I would like to understand if this is a bug in Chrome, or if I'm just misunderstanding something.

Comment: I can reproduce in Chrome v. 108.0.5359.125. I am on Windows. Are you on Linux?

Comment: Reproduce on Windows, Chrome v. 108.0.5359.125. Also, it does not occur when the screen is expanded more than 250%.

Comment: Cannot reproduce in Chrome v. 108.0.5359.124 MacOS.

Comment: This is happening to me too on Chrome 119 on Windows.  Adding `backface-visibility: hidden;` seems to fix it.  So weird